# Problem with document scanner plugin: extra dependencies add on time of build

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-react

I have a problem with the ionic react document scanner, as I build the app in some file extra dependency adds into that file and I have to remove that dependency to make application workable, otherwise, it won’t work.

Here is the path of extra dependency, it's showing file not found:

> /Users/ionic/builds/project-0/ios/capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins/sources/CordovaPluginDocumentScanner/src/ios/IRLDocumentScanner.framework/PrivateHeaders/IRLCameraView.h:14:9:
> 'IRLScannerViewController.h' file not found

Now, important thing is that I am sending the code to the client and he makes build from the ionic hub and he is not able to comment or remove that dependency from the ionic hub as he builds on ionic hub dependency came and he can’t remove it, now I’m not being able to find the solution of this issue from the previous week.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
#import "IRLScannerViewController.h"
```

to

```
#import <IRLDocumentScanner.h/IRLScannerViewController.h>
```

[IRLDocumentScanner.h file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BMhD.png)